Bad query plan in postgresql 16.2
I seem to keep getting a very bad query plan in PostgreSQL 16.2 when selecting a small number of rows from a large aggregated table via a join.
Consider the following setup:
CREATE TABLE large_table (a integer, b integer, PRIMARY KEY (a, b));
INSERT INTO large_table SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10000) a(a), generate_series(1,10) b(b);

CREATE TABLE small_table (a integer PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO small_table VALUES (1),(1000),(7000),(15),(9999);

ANALYZE large_table, small_table;

Then
EXPLAIN 
SELECT
    a,
    array_agg
FROM
    (SELECT a, array_agg(b) FROM large_table GROUP BY a) _
    JOIN small_table USING (a);

results in the following plan:
Merge Join  (cost=0.42..3705.18 rows=250 width=36)
   Merge Cond: (large_table.a = small_table.a)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.29..3665.43 rows=10011 width=36)
         Group Key: large_table.a
         ->  Index Only Scan using large_table_pkey on large_table  (cost=0.29..3040.29 rows=100000 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan using small_table_pkey on small_table  (cost=0.13..12.21 rows=5 width=4)

If I understand this correctly, PostgreSQL first aggregates the whole large_table before it picks out the five rows we actually care about, although the planner is clearly aware that doing so is very expensive and that small_table only contains five rows.
Selecting the five rows explicitly, on the other hand, gives the expected result:
EXPLAIN 
SELECT
    a,
    array_agg
FROM
    (SELECT a, array_agg(b) FROM large_table GROUP BY a) _
WHERE a IN (1,1000,7000,15,9999);

GroupAggregate  (cost=0.29..23.21 rows=50 width=36)
   Group Key: large_table.a
   ->  Index Only Scan using large_table_pkey on large_table  (cost=0.29..22.34 rows=50 width=8)
         Index Cond: (a = ANY ('{1,1000,7000,15,9999}'::integer[]))

I've run into variations of this issue on several occasions lately and it is becoming a serious problem. Is there anything obvious I'm missing here? If not, is there a way around this problem, if listing the rows explicitly is not an option?

What would you expect the "good" plan to look like? Join first, then aggregate? Perhaps a CTE might help.

Exactly. Pick out the few values of a we actually care about, then aggregate over those only, pretty much what happens in the second version. CTE doesn't help, neither does a condition like WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM small_table).

You'd still do an index scan on large_table and a join, no matter how you order those operations, so doing an aggregation while scanning makes more sense, as opposed to doing it separately. Postgres cannot magically guess what values of a will be in the final result, unless you explicitly tell it. Besides, looking at the theoretical plan is a futile exercise; do explain (analyze, buffers) and possibly also include I/O timing to learn where the time is actually spent.

I can assure you that aggregating vs. joining first makes a huge difference in practice, otherwise I wouldn't be here. And the planner doesn't have to magically guess anything, according to the explain output it is fully aware that it will only need five rows.

Both of these queries perform according to your view. Though I am v13 so I cannot say for certain in your case. Both of these queries have a significantly lower cost and execution time than the original in my setup.
I recall watching a presentation from a PostgreSQL conference where this was discussed. The optimizer is guessing how many records might satisfy the join to decide if it should join first and then aggregate (i.e. most of the rows would not meet the join condition so aggregation is only needed on a few rows).
The materialized CTE had a slightly lower cost in my version/hardware setup though probably irrelevant if in production. But your case may vary. The materialized CTE should force the the join first if that is what you want.
with join_them as (SELECT large_table.a, large_table.b 
                   FROM large_table 
                      JOIN small_table 
                         USING (a))
SELECT a, array_agg(b) 
from join_them 
group by a;


with join_them as materialized (SELECT large_table.a, large_table.b  
                                FROM large_table 
                                  JOIN small_table 
                                   USING (a))
SELECT a, array_agg(b) from 
join_them 
group by a;


Thanks! Explicitly joining before aggregating solves the problem, but unfortunately it's not really a practical solution for my case, as the aggregation of large_table is part of a view and I would like to be flexible in how I select rows from that view.
I also don't think I get the explanation: As you can see from the explain output, the planner is fully aware that it's only going to need five rows, and it's still choosing to do the aggregation first.
